# Display non-duplicate ID while maintaining the other ID

Tags: reactjs

I have the following array of objects.

```
[
    {
        "question_ID": 13,
        "question_desc": "Question 1",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 17,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 13,
        "question_desc": "Question 1",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 18,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 13,
        "question_desc": "Question 1",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 19,
        "answer_desc": "C",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 14,
        "question_desc": "Question 2",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 20,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 14,
        "question_desc": "Question 2",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 21,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 15,
        "question_desc": "Question 3",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 22,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 15,
        "question_desc": "Question 3",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 23,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 16,
        "question_desc": "Question 4",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 24,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 16,
        "question_desc": "Question 4",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 25,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 17,
        "question_desc": "Question 5",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 26,
        "answer_desc": "Testing Answer",
        "answer_result": 0
    }
]
```

What I want to achieve is to get only 1 question_ID, I mean I want to get question_ID from 13,14,15,16,17 but only display 1 time, so I can calculate the length of the total question, but at the same time how can I display all the answer_ID based on that question (like question_ID 13 has answer_ID 17,18,19), because if I get rid of those duplicate question_ID, the answer will be lost, too. I think so. Can someone please help me, thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k6Vz.jpg

Comment: post your json object here and dont use images. format your object as code. it will be much easier for us to help you that way

Comment: Can I use POSTMAN to do it? Because I'm using Axios at ReactJS to get the API from MySQL.

Comment: copy your json object here. edit the question and add your json object

Comment: I have editted and added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `reduce` method in your array in order to group your elements based on question_ID.

If, for example questionArray is your array of objects, then use the following code in order to group them

```
   let grouped = questionArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
          const property = obj['question_ID'];
          acc[property] = acc[property] || [];
          acc[property].push(obj);
          return acc;
     }, {});
```

Then in order to find the total distinct questions, you can do the following:

```
console.log(Object.keys(grouped))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help a lot! I never thought I could use reduce like this.

Comment: glad i helped :)

Comment: I'm sorry but can I ask you one more question here, I have followed your instruction and successfully get the length and display the total question, as well as display it as a group as I want in the console.log, but when I want to get its property out I can't get it. I console.log (grouped), it displays an array contains {13: Array(3), 14: Array(2), 15: Array(2), 16: Array(2), 17: Array(1)}, I tried console.log(grouped[0]) but get undefined, sorry for bothering you again. I have never manipulated this kind of array nested in an array like this before.

Comment: you need to reference it as grouped[13]

Comment: unless you need to find the first property, so you use this `Object.keys(grouped)[0]`

Comment: question description is available as the group object. then in order to get the answers' info you need to iterate e.g. `grouped[13].forEach` etc etc

Comment: I have found out Object.keys(grouped)[0] way at first, but unfortunately, that's not what I'm looking for, the `grouped` contains 13,14,15,16,17, each of that is an array, too, and inside it has index structure 0,1,2, etc, I want to go inside of that to get the Question_description and Answer_description, I have to browse the internet a bit but unlucky there's no method I can find to use to solve this right now. The grouped[13], I just console log, it's what I want, but I don't know how to get it independently, because some of my quiz ID is not continuous, like 5 6 8 10.

Comment: I'll try the forEach, thanks for still being here with me :)